# python imaplib returns only half the messages from exchange 2013

Tags: python, exchange-server, imap

I tried to find out what's the issue here. I don't get it.

PROBLEM: I get only half the messages from the INBOX on one run. When I run another time it gets another half of the messages and so on 'til there is none left.

SETUP: I am trying with python 2.7.3 (I know it's old) on Debian 7 to fetch messages with imaplib.fetch from an Exchange Server 2013.

```
def fetch_mails():
    messages = []
    mailbox = IMAP4_SSL(host = mail_host, port = mail_port)
    mailbox.login(mail_user, mail_password)
    mailbox.select()
    mailcount = mailbox.search(None, 'ALL')[1][0]
    mailcount = sum(1 for num in mailcount.split())
    for i in xrange(1, mailcount+1):
        mailbox.select()
        status, data = mailbox.fetch(str(i), '(RFC822)')
        current = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
        messages.append(current)
        mailbox.store(i, '+FLAGS', r'\Deleted')
    return messages
```

ERROR: 'The specified message set is invalid.'

Has anyone an idea why that happens? In the end I can process all the mails, but not in one run. 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `mailcount = sum(1 for num in mailcount.split())` is silly.  `len(mailcount.split())` is way shorter, but also the return value of select() is the number of messages in the mailbox, so you wouldn't need to search at all if using sequence numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two problems here that together conspire to show this behaviour:

1. You are using message sequence numbers.  Messages are consecutively numbered from 1-n, where N is the number of messages in the mailbox.  Whenever messages are removed, all the sequence numbers shift.
2. You are re-SELECT-ing the mailbox between each message.  This gives the server a chance to expunge deleted messages, thereby shifting all sequence numbers down.

So, the code downloads Message 1, marks it deleted, and reselects the mailbox, allowing the server to expunge it, moving messages 2-N down to messages 1 - (N-1).  You then download message two (which was previously the third message), and repeat.  Because of this, you only download every other message.

There are two ways to fix it:

1. Remove mailbox.select() from your loop.
2. Use UIDs instead, which are stable even when messages are being deleted.

Here is your code with both changes:

```
def fetch_mails():
    messages = []
    mailbox = IMAP4_SSL(host = mail_host, port = mail_port)
    mailbox.login(mail_user, mail_password)
    mailbox.select()
    uids = mailbox.uid('SEARCH', 'ALL')[1][0].split()
    for uid in uids:
        status, data = mailbox.uid('FETCH', uid, '(RFC822)')
        current = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
        messages.append(current)
        mailbox.uid('STORE', uid, '+FLAGS', r'\Deleted')
    return messages
```

I have not tested the code, so you may need to make some small changes.

Comment: FWIW this code will work better on python 3.5 than 2.7, since 3.5 has a much more sensible size limit for search responses than earlier versions do.